# Perl DBI MySQL: Check if column is UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Using Perl DBI, how to check if (given a table name and column name) a MySQL column is UNIQUE (that is has UNIQUE constraint)?

Comment: Get more & better answers by detailing what you have already tried.

Comment: @MartinCowie How would explaining what he tried get better answers? It makes sense to ask people what they've tried when they say "my code isn't working, help me debug it" without including any code, but it makes no sense here. The question is quite clear; cluttering it up with a bunch of failed attempts at a solution would just add useless noise.

Comment: Please would you explain what you want to do with this information? It will help us to formulate a more accurate answer for you. It seems a strange thing on which to base the flow of a program

Answer (score 2):

This function should return true for columns with an UNIQUE constraint, or false otherwise.

Input values are DBI (mysql) object, table name and column name.

```
sub check_uniq {
    my ($dbh, $table, $column) = @_;
    $table =~ s/\`//;
    $table = '`' . $table . '`';
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SHOW INDEX FROM ' . $table);
    $sth->execute();
    while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
        if (($row->{Column_name} eq $column) && (!$row->{Non_unique})) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```